# Как запустить Fastapi так, чтобы одновременно с ним запустилась админка Django? Как все это сделать через один скрипт?

Tags: python, django-admin, fastapi

У меня проект на `Fastapi`, а админку сделали на `Django`. Понимаю, что это не очень популярная тема, но вот такая задача встала передо мной. Я не понимаю, как сделать одновременный запуск. Сейчас я их запускаю отдельно на разных портах.

Совсем не знаю, как подступиться к этой задаче. Были идеи на счет `docker-compose`, но опять же они там запускаются по отдельности.

Comment: А какой результат ты хочешь, я не совсем понял?

Answer (score 0):

Запустить два сервера на одном порте не получится, да и зачем это нужно.

Нужно отдельно запустить сервер `FastAPI` и отдельно запустить `Django`.
И админка Django вполне себе будет выполнять свою работу.

Если нужно чтобы сайт открывался по `http://localhost:8000/`, а админка была доступна по адресу `http://localhost:8000/admin`, а не `http://localhost:8001/admin`.

То можно создать прокси-сервер например на nginx. Он будет распределять запросы между этими серверами.

Пример файла nginx:

```
server {
    listen 8000;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }

    location /admin {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для запуска вместе нужно одно положить в другое. Сделать это можно через wsgi. https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/wsgi/

Джанга кладется в wsgi мидлваре, которое запускается на фастапи.